# Is there any yoga which helps in levitation and disappearing?

Tags: puranas, history, belief, yoga, meditation

Is there any yoga that helps in levitation and disappearing? Heard enough stories about this that Baba Yogis do it in Himalayas but without any proofs.

What type of Yogis are they? Are they referred to Aghoris or plain Yogis? Can a common man attain such levels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the middle stage of Yogic practice (a stage which is known as the Ghata Avastha), an adept Yogi obtains various Siddhis (perfections). Among which floating in the air and becoming invisible are there.

Quoting from [Shiva Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Samhita):

> 42. When the Yogi, though remaining in Padmasana, can rise in the air and leave the ground, then know that he has gained Vayu-siddhi
>     (success over air), which destroys the darkness of the world.
>
> 54 The Yogi acquires the following powers :—vakya siddhi (prophecy), transporting himself everywhere at will (Kamachari),
> clairvoyance (duradristhi),  clairaudience (durashruti), subtle-sight
> (shukshma-drishti), and the power of entering another’s body
> (parakaypravesana), turning base metals to gold by rubbing them with
> his excrements and urine, **and the power of becoming invisible, and
> lastly, moving in the air.**
>
> **Verses 42 and 54 from Chapter 3.**

These Siddhis are obtained by practicing Yoga mostly Pranayama.

Comment: Thank you @Rickross for the evidences. If pranayama is sufficient to attain this, how long it would take? Then what leads to Hata Yoga done by Aghoris? Just curious to know  these?

Comment: The basis of the practice that leads to such Siddhis is Pranayama but you have to read the entire chapter to know what all are actually needed. Also, practice must be done under the guidance of the Guru. Lastly, Vayu Siddhi, that leads to Bhuchari/Khechari (flying in the air) Siddhi is obtained when the Anahata Chakra is pierced/mastered. So, it is wrong to think that just any ordinary practice of Pranayama would lead to such Siddhi @Hansiemithun

Comment: It is said and heard that Guru will find his/her Shishya. Even if people reach to some Guru, they deny teaching. What attracts Gurus to find their Shishya and how to find proper Gurus who have attained something... Not all Gurus are good enough and there are fake masters everywhere collecting money... Any thoughts on this @Rickross?

Comment: Whatever you have said is right .. I agree @Hansiemithun

Answer (score 0):

> **कायरूपसंयमात्तद्ग्राह्यशक्तिस्तम्भे
> चक्षुःप्रकाशासम्प्रयोगेऽन्तर्धानम्॥२१॥
> Kāyarūpasaṁyamāttadgrāhyaśaktistambhe
> cakṣuḥprakāśāsamprayoge’ntardhānam ||21||**
>
> *Through samyama on one’s physical form, suspending the energy thus
> generated, and uncoupling it with the light perceived through the
> eyes, one attains the ability to suspend vision. (21)*
>
> By performing samyama on the physical form of the body, holding that
> energy and thickening it, and not letting eyes and light work
> together, invisibility comes about.

- Yoga Sutras of Patanjali 3.21

I've personally heard from a few acquaintances giving anecdotal info about some yogis doing such things. Personally, I'm not interested in these.