# Do rishies and maharishi attain super power after long years of meditation or other act's?

Tags: rishi

After long years of meditation can a maharishi attain super power like the ability to use Alchemy (the medieval forerunner of chemistry, concerned with the transmutation of matter, in particular with attempts to convert base metals into gold or find a universal elixir) or flying.

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43868/4732) answers your question. Those powers are called Yogic Siddhis and are obtained after severe practice of Yoga (which involves meditation, pranayam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do rishies and maharishi attain super power after long years of meditation or other act's?

Yes, constant performance of religious rites like constant recitation of the Vedas gives supernatural powers:

> [Manusmriti 4.148](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200256.html) - By the constant recitation of the Veda, by purification, by austerity, and by doing no harm to living beings, **he remembers his previous birth.**