# Why it is forbidden to tell other about what one can see during meditation?

Tags: meditation, dream

I came to know many times that it is not good to tell someone else about what one has seen in his/her meditation(or in a dream related to God). But, I am not aware why?

(i) Can it be explained why it is forbidden?

(ii) What can be the consequences?

Text related to this topic is also acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: Who said this, I mean is there any source

Comment: Meditation is a spiritual practice and spiritual practices and their outcomes are usually required to be kept secret. You many find the following answer useful: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43801/4732

Comment: @Rickross advaita vedanta is also result of spiritual practice. Adi Shankara was enlightened and then he wrote advaita vedanta. If he can say, why can't we.

Comment: This is a personal question which can only be answered by one's guru. For many people it is simply a person's ego boasting - which is not conducive to spiritual development and only leads to personal vanity.